# JSON Stringify doesnt format the same into component

Tags: javascript

I have an array that I need to format using JSON Stringify. I am using the Chakra UI  component to display the text but it doesnt show correctly in the component. In the console it is showing how I want it however.
This is the formatted text:

```
[
  {
    "price": "15.99",
    "size": "m"
  },
  {
    "price": "2.99",
    "size": "s"
  }
]
```

This is how I use it in the component:

```
<Code children={JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)} />
```

But running the app in the component it shows:

```
[ { "price": "15.99", "size": "m" }, { "price": "2.99", "size": "s" } ]
```

With no line breaks. Ive tried wrapping the JSON.stringify term in a `p` tag but didnt work. Not sure if there is a trick to this or a property in the code css that cuts off the lines

Comment: You can use a `<pre>` tag or CSS property `white-space: pre;` (or `white-space: pre-wrap;` if you want long lines to wrap)

Comment: @Rick the OP explicitly added line breaks by using `JSON.stringify(..., ..., 2)` and is wondering why they don't show up on the page. That's due to how HTML renders text though and not really because of anything related to JavaScript.

Comment: stringily is not going to add any new line characters, so if you want it to be formatted in html you will need to parse it and add a bunch of html tags.

Comment: @Rick that's not true, you can use the third argument to `JSON.stringify` to enable pretty-printing. (And that's what the OP is already doing.)

Comment: @CherryDT is there an example of this somewhere?

Comment: The narrative is faulty. `JSON.stringify()` works like it should, you displaying it is the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @CherryDT commented, you just need to use the correct element to display the JSON output, and `<pre>` is best suited, unless you use CSS to alter the behaviour of another element.

```js
const data = [
  {
    "price": "15.99",
    "size": "m"
  },
  {
    "price": "2.99",
    "size": "s"
  }
];

const element = document.getElementById(`app`);

element.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
```

```html
<pre id="app"></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your use of `JSON.stringify()` is correct. Yet you have to set the container to display those linebreaks.

```js
const data = [
  {
    "price": "15.99",
    "size": "m"
  },
  {
    "price": "2.99",
    "size": "s"
  }
]

document.querySelector('p').textContent = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)
```

```css
p{
  white-space: pre
}
```

```html
<p>
</p>
```